# Python/Django data to jquery alert box

Tags: jquery, django

I have a function which get some data. Result is for example:

```
sites = Site.objects.filter(is_active=False)
```

Function runs after button is pressed in django admin.py:

```
def my_function(self, request):
    sites = Site.objects.filter(is_active=False)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META["HTTP_REFERER"], {'result': sites})

def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(ConfigAdmin, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = [
        url(r'^my_function/$', self.export),
    ]
    return my_urls + urls
```

This is my button code:

```
<input type="submit"  onclick="location.href='my_function/'" value="{% trans 'My_function' %}" />
```

I would like to put result to jquery alert box. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Get what result? `my_function` doesn't return a result. In fact, that function **does nothing at all**.

Comment: return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META["HTTP_REFERER"], {'result': sites}) - is it ok now? Sites is just an examlpe. Function check a lot of sites and makes changes (edit objects). I would like to show something like: "There are 5 modified sites (link here)".

Comment: You must do an ajax call using JQuery and display the result in an alert box.

Comment: No that still doesn't make sense. You can't return a redirect *and* a result. As Selcuk says, use Ajax; then you don't need the redirect at all.

Comment: In your view you can use request.is_ajax() https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/http/request/#HttpRequest.is_ajax . If the request is asynchronous send back your data to the browser and display it in an alert, otherwise do things the old school way. For the ajax part: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your view needs to return a valid json object so that the jquery callback can process it. Django has a built-in `JsonResponse` that we can use to serialize our data.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def my_function(self, request):
    sites = Site.objects.filter(is_active=False).values_list('name', flat=True)
    return JsonResponse({'result': sites}, safe=False)
```

Now, we need to show this on the page with jquery. You can do this by binding a click callback to a link, and alerting the result of the view.

```
<a href="#" id="my-button">{% trans 'My_function' %}</a>

<script>
$('#my-button').click(function(){
    $.get('my_function/', function(data){
        alert(data.result);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I will try to check your solution. There is a problem with json. I get an error: "is not JSON serializable". I must read about json. Excuse for my bad english...

Comment: Ah, yes. `sites` will have to be processed again, Maybe you just want a list of the site names? Lists and dicts are all that can be serialized. `sites` is a queryset at this point.

Comment: I updated the answer so that `sites` is now Json serializable.

Answer (score 0):

I made it that way. It works but I don't know is it a proper way:

my admin.py:

```
def my_function(self, request):
    sites = Site.objects.filter(is_active=False)
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = sites
        return HttpResponse(message)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META["HTTP_REFERER"])
```

my .js file:

```
$('#content > p > input[type="submit"]:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
        $.get("my_function/", function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    });
```

my template file:

```
<input type="submit"  onclick="location.href='my_function/'" value="{% trans 'My_function' %}" />
```

Is it ok? It displays alert box with variable from my function.